How to implement premade AI from openai into my Python code, so user of telegram bot could receive a respond from AI
client = OpenAI(api_key=os.environ.get("PROJ_API"))
assistant_id = functions.create_assistant(client)
bot = telebot.TeleBot('BOT_TOKEN')

#openai.api_key = "ASST_ID"
#try:
#    model_info = openai.models.retrieve("ASST_ID")
#    print(model_info)
#except Exception as e:
#    print("Error:", e)




@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_message(message):
    try:
        
        prompt = "user: " + message.text + "\nAssistant:"

        
        response = client.chat.completions.create(
            model= "gpt-3.5-turbo-0125",  
            messages=[{
                "role": "user",
                "content": message.text
            }, {
                "role": "assistant",
                "content": "assistant: " + prompt
            }],
            max_tokens=150)

        # Send the response back to the user
        bot.reply_to(message, response.choices[0].message.content)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        bot.reply_to(
            message,
            "Unfortunately, an error occurred while processing your request.")

I'm trying to use my assistant which was made on platform openai, so it would make a response to user's message in telegram bot, but whenever I'm sending a message to a bot, it responds like it is a default `gpt-3.5-turbo-0125 without using any instructions and storage files, so AI response in playground and AI in telegram bot give me different answers
